# Returning Custom views for NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException 404 error in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

Whenever user types a wrong url in browser it results in `NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException` I want to return a customize view rather than the default view that spring provides with a message. I have `@AdviceController` in which I tried to catch it through  `@ExceptionHAndler(NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException.class)` and return a view but it didn't work. I also inherited `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver` and overidden the method that handles `NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException`, this also didn't work. I also tried to register view names to exceptions through extending `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` `setExecptionMapping`(in same `@AdviceController` class) method that also didn't one work. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Am I even right about that spring throws `NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException` when it doesn't find any mappings in controller Can somebody tell me how to return custom views for Spring Exceptions that are matched with HTTP error codes.

This is my @ControllerAdvice

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerController extends     
DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver {

@ExceptionHandler(NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException.class)
public String handleException(NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException.class, Model model) {

    String error = th.getMessage();
    model.addAttribute("error", error);
    model.addAttribute(new User());
    return "login";
   }

@override
protected ModelAndView handleNoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException
(NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException ex, HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

      ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("notfound");
      return mav;
   }
}
```

**UPDATE: Solution**

The reason that `NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException` does not get raised is because Dispatcher Servlet delegates request to default servlet handler(in my case `DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler`) and considered it handled. The workaround that I have implemented is that I have created a handler method with mapping '/*' that is executed when there is no specific mapping found in any controller and there I through new `NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException` which can be caught in @ExceptionHandler and then returned a custom view. However, I do not know the downside of handling exception like this. If any let me know.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

...

@RequestMapping(value = "/*", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public void handleAtLast(HttpServletRequest request) throws NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException {
    throw new NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException(request);
  }
}
```

ExceptionHandlerController.java

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerController extends DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver {
   @ExceptionHandler(NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException.class)
   public String handleNoSuchMethodtFoundException(NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException ex){
       return "error/notfound";
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this [article will help you](http://www.javabeat.net/spring-mvc-404-error-page/)

Comment: That is a custom exception thrown when user enters nothing in URI where a name is expected. I want to return a view for every wrong url entered in a browser that results in NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException.

Comment: NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException is  @Deprecated

Comment: @BigDong Since it's deprecated, do you know how can I replace that? The Javadoc says in favor of annotation-driven method, but what should I do? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class AppWideExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class) // replace with your exception Class
    public String errorHandler(){
        System.out.println("caught exception");
        return "home"; // your view
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this. It works for your customize exception but it doesn't work for Exception thrown by Spring itself for something going wrong with dispatcher servlet

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException` does not get raised is because Dispatcher Servlet delegates request to default servlet handler(in my case `DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler`) and considered it handled. The workaround that I have implemented is that I have created a handler method with mapping '/*' that is executed when there is no specific mapping found in any controller and there I through new `NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException` which can be caught in @ExceptionHandler and then returned a custom view. However, I do not know the downside of handling exception like this. If any let me know.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

...

@RequestMapping(value = "/*", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public void handleAtLast(HttpServletRequest request) throws NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException {
    throw new NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException(request);
  }
}
```

ExceptionHandlerController.java

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerController extends DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver {
   @ExceptionHandler(NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException.class)
   public String handleNoSuchMethodtFoundException(NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException ex){
       return "error/notfound";
    }
}
```